# How to extract a text from a url while conditionally rendering the images using an Arrayformula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This formula below does extract the file ID and yields the correct image url. Now, how to fetch the correct url to extract that ID from by verifying a key using `VLOOKUP()` maybe?

I've seen that `REGEXEXTRACT()` requires `JOIN()` and could this be the reason why it doesn't work?

Current formula doesn't populate the rows, but only the one it's sitting in:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="&regexextract(VLOOKUP($F$3:$F$100,$I:$I,2,0),"d/(.+)/view")),""))
```

Here's a [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing) for tests, if you feel like operating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is working! Just change `$I:$I` with `$I:$J`.

You need to put the whole range including the column to look at and the column with the results.